# How to collapse index with same value in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below code get me the dataframe as below. for the index level=0, 1 and 2 only shows once. How to have the same behavior in level=1? I want  below results:

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a',100, 'tom'],[1,'b',200,'ann'], [1,'a',200,'pet'],[2,'a',100,'dig'],[2,'b',200,'goo']], columns=['n', 'alpha','number', 'text'])
test.set_index(['n','alpha']).sort_index(level=0, axis=0)

         number text
n alpha             
1 a         100  tom
  a         200  pet
  b         200  ann
2 a         100  dig
  b         200  goo
```

What I want:

```
         number text
n alpha             
1 a         100  tom
            200  pet
  b         200  ann
2 a         100  dig
  b         200  goo
```

Comment: Just being curious. What is the purpose of intentionally leaving it in the expected output's format? I just want to know when it is applicable to do it for future work.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick , at least when you print it. Notice here you will have 3 level multiple index, this is only for view purpose , not recommended you overwrite your original dataframe

```
test.assign(d='').set_index('d',append=True).rename_axis(['n','alpha',''])
Out[190]: 
          number text
n alpha              
1 a          100  tom
             200  ann
  b          200  pet
2 a          100  dig
  b          200  goo
```